# Is it possible to use composer's archive feature to compress a project locally?

Tags: php, composer-php, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Is it possible to use composer's archive feature to compress a project locally (similar to using zip)? For instance, I tried `composer archive my-repo/project --format=zip --file test-archive`. It worked in the sense that it created a zip file called `test-archive`, but composer did it by first going to my satis repo and pulling down a copy of the project.

I also have this defined in my composer.json

```
"archive": {
        "exclude": [
            ".*",
            "!.gitignore",
            "node_modules/",
            "vendor/",
            "www/",
            "composer/",
            "*.lst",
            "*.yml"
        ]
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is use the archive feature as part of a bitbucket pipelines build process. The goal is to compress the project files (excluding some) and pass them to the Downloads page for the bitbucket repo. I have a working step using zip, but archive uses a better syntax for excluding files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok - now I feel a little silly, but since someone kindly upvoted the question, I'll answer it. The documentation was slightly confusing to me. Composer doesn't actually need `my-repo/project` to compress the file correctly. So if you do `composer archive --format=zip --file test-archive` it will compress in place at the root of your project.

Comment: NB - if you need `/vendor` make sure to explicitly include it by using `"!vendor/*"` instead of excluding it as in the above question.

Comment: How exactly can I include my vendor folder?

Comment: In your `composer.json` file, you can declare an `archive` property with an `exclude` sub-property. You can explicitly include a directory or file like this `"!vendor/*"` or `!fileName`. I don't think the [cli composer command accepts include/exclude options](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#archive)